# setting color in listviewitem

Tags: java, android

I want to colorize an Item in a ListView with this code:

`holder.txtPosition = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtPosition);` 
`holder.txtPosition.setTextColor(0xFF00CC00);`.

It is working great BUT: It colors every tenth item too. For example: I set the color for the first item, so every tenth item gets the color too.

If i scroll down and scroll up again, much more gets colored.

In this image, i only colored the first "User-voting" Text and then scrolled down very fast and scrolled back to top.

[image: The green Text]

What kind of sorcery is this?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class List extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem>{

    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    ListItem data[] = null;

    public List(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ListItem[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data; 
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        WeatherHolder holder = null;
        ListItem entry = data[position];

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new WeatherHolder();
            holder.txtVideos = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtVideos);
            holder.txtPosition = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtPosition);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            holder.txtcomments = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtcomment);

            row.setTag(holder);

            if (entry.fav){
                //row.setBackgroundColor(0xFFfcf6bb);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        holder.txtTitle.setText(entry.teilnehmer);
        holder.txtPosition.setText(entry.position);

        int num = Integer.parseInt(entry.videos);
        if (num == 0 || num > 1){
            holder.txtVideos.setText(entry.videos + " Videos");
        } else {
            holder.txtVideos.setText(entry.videos + " Video");
        }

        if (holder.txtPosition.getText().equals("Ausgeschieden")){
            holder.txtPosition.setTextColor(0xFFFF0000);
        } else if(holder.txtPosition.getText().equals("User-Voting")){
            holder.txtPosition.setTextColor(0xFF00CC00);
        }

        num = Integer.parseInt(entry.comment);
        if (num == 0 || num > 1){
            holder.txtcomments.setText(entry.comment + " Kommentare");
        } else {
            holder.txtcomments.setText(entry.comment + " Kommentar");
        }
        return row;
    }

    static class WeatherHolder
    {
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtVideos;
        TextView txtPosition;
        TextView txtcomments;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code where you create the list item elements :-)

Comment: in which trigger you are doing this coloring?

Comment: i have added the complete class.

Comment: see view recycling in ListViews here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're recycling your ListView elements (which is a good thing). But when such a View is passed to your `getView` method it's still in the state of the last element it held; so if you specify `setColor` this value will also be applied to the next text that will be injected into the container. Therefore you should also reset the color definition when you repopulate the recycled view:

```
if (holder.txtPosition.getText().equals("Ausgeschieden")) {
    holder.txtPosition.setTextColor(0xFFFF0000);
} else if (holder.txtPosition.getText().equals("User-Voting")) {
    holder.txtPosition.setTextColor(0xFF00CC00);
} else {
    holder.txtPosition.setTextColor(R.color.your_default);
}
```

Comment: is it the same with `row.seBackgroundColor`?

Comment: I don't see anything about `backgroundColor` in your code; but yes: This applies to all view properties you change. They all need to be reset when you recycle a view (you're recycling every time when row is not `null` in your first if/else block!).

Comment: it is commented out after the `if (entry.fav)` line.

Comment: Yeah, it should be: `if(entry.fav) { /* setFavColor */ } else { /* setDefaultColor */ }` and it shouldn't be within the surround if/else block.